# Video artifacts on xmonad

Tags: video, xmonad

I suddenly started getting this type of artifacts while using xmonad.

[image: glitch 1]
[image: glitch 2]

The pattern changes and often disappears after some mouse movements.

I didn't do any video-related updates, nor xmonad updates. This does not happen when using gnome. Similar glitches also manifest when typing in gui applications, but not in the terminal emulator nor in emacs.

I have tried both with and without nvidia driver, the issue is always present.

I am using debian bookworm with linux 5.14.0-2-amd64.

Do you have any idea what this could be related to?

Comment: I get the same artifacts in Ubuntu (18 and 20). It's mostly not a big deal but it makes some apps unusable. I was saddened to see you got no bites :(

Comment: FWIW, upgrading to Ubuntu 22 fixed it for me. I know that helps very little, but somewhere in that upgrade some package got bumped...